# Out of curiosity: Which is better for creating a sum? sum(list) vs accumulation

Tags: python, list, concatenation

I am calculating the total distance of a route (for a traveling salesman problem) and I am curious about which is better:  summing a list of integers, or using total += value (not sure what the technical term for this is.. concatenation I believe?).  In other words:

```
totalDistance = [distance(location, location+1) for location in route]
return sum(totalDistance)
```

or

```
totalDistance = 0
for location in route:
    totalDistance += distance(location, location+1)
return totalDistance
```

distance() returns an `int` value, and the number of locations varies between about 0 to 100 for different routes.
Thoughts on either method (or a completely different way) appreciated!

Edit:

Accumulation , not Concatenation.

Comment: I think you mean *accumulation* instead of *concatenation*. What do you mean by *better*, faster?

Comment: That's the word I was looking for!  And by better, I guess I mean faster, cleaner and less intensive on memory.

Comment: "Faster" can be profiled, but my money's on the list comp. "Cleaner" is subjective -- people like to see things differently. "Memory-intensive" is most definitely summing a generator expression e.g. `total_dist = sum(distance(location, location+1) for location in route)`

Comment: @AdamSmith, why do you think generator expressions are more memory intensive than lists? (apart from very small lists)

Comment: @gnibbler I don't. He's looking for less memory intensive, so I recommended a genexp

Comment: I think I read somewhere that when you use += it re-creates a new variable every time rather than just update the value.  This is what first led me to consider using a generator expression instead.

Comment: @josibake, `+=` generally works differently for mutable vs immutable objects. `int` are immutable, so it's necessary to create a new object each time (There are exceptions - such as small ints in cpython).

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-generator_expression) with `sum`:

```
return sum(distance(location, location+1) for location in route)
```

This solution avoids creating an unnecessary list like the first solution (saves on memory consumption) and is also a lot more concise than the second (cleanliness counts).

That said, you could always merge the first solution into a one-liner:

```
return sum([distance(location, location+1) for location in route])
```

But then, as I said above, why create a list just to throw it away?

Comment: Did you profile this? I had the impression that list comprehensions/generator expressions where in general faster than `for` loops.

Comment: I like this.. I didn't realize you could sum a generator expression all on the same line!

Comment: I think the generator expression is faster

Comment: Even though the for loop is faster, isn't it re-creating the `number` variable 100 times?  Is that a bad thing?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham - I would think that too, but the results you see are real.  Let me go run the tests again to confirm.

Comment: `for` loops is much faster than genexp for `pypy 2.2.1`. Good to know details like that if you're trying to use pypy to speed things up.

Comment: @iCodez, on a large input a generator expression is always slightly faster using cpython on my machine.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham - True, my inputs were small.  I went and ran the tests again and got mixed results, so I'm guessing that something interfered before (not sure what though). I'm going to take down my comments on speed for now.  gnibbler's answer though shows that my statements were at least correct in PyPy. :*)

Comment: @josibake - It is reassigning the name `number` 100 times.  But as gnibbler's test shows, it is still the fastest solution for some implementations such as PyPy.  Others however have the generator expression as the fastest (the comments on my answer show this).  However, placing speed aside, the list comprehension creates an unnecessary list (wastes memory) and the for-loop is unnecessarily verbose as well as a little tedious to type.  Thus, I would still use the generator expression.

Answer (score 1):

Best is to just use a generator expression with `sum`

```
return sum(distance(location, location+1) for location in route)
```

This saves the overhead of creating a list.
totalDistance = [distance(location, location+1) for location in route]

The `for` loop version also doesn't create a list. It's fine, just a little verbose compared to using `sum`. `sum` exists precisely for cases like this

How does `location+1` work? Seems like it should be the next item from route

---

For interest I compared @iCodez examples in PyPy 2.2.1. First run of each function is to allow the JIT to compile the function

```
>>>> from timeit import timeit
>>>> def f():
....     number = 0
....     for i in range(100):
....         number += 1
.... 
>>>> timeit(f)
0.3245859146118164
>>>> timeit(f)
0.2913198471069336

>>>> def g():
....     lst = [i for i in range(100)]
....     sum(lst)
.... 
>>>> timeit(g)
0.8840188980102539
>>>> timeit(g)
0.8698201179504395

>>>> def h():
....     sum(i for i in range(100))
.... 
>>>> timeit(h)
2.8281970024108887
>>>> timeit(h)
2.8702847957611084
```

Wow..genexp performance is much worse

Comment: That wasn't my actual code - just kind of a rough idea.  What I have written is `distance(locations[i], locations[i+1] for i in range(len(locations)-1)`

Answer (score 0):

On my machine, iterate through a generator is slower than a list:

```
from timeit import timeit

# just for simulation
def distance(la, lb):
    return abs(la-lb)

# for simulation, too    
def route():
    return xrange(10000)

# the longer(code) and faster but wasteful(memory) way
def longer_faster_wasteful():
    return sum([distance(location, location+1) for location in route()])

# the shorter(code) and saving(memory) but slower way
def shorter_slower_saving():
    return sum(distance(location, location+1) for location in route())

# print 2.01163072818 on my machine
print timeit(longer_faster_wasteful, number=100)

# print 2.91834802689 on my machine
print timeit(shorter_slower_saving, number=100)
```